# Adding License Key for Froala in Angular 1

Tags: jquery, angularjs, froala

Does anyone know how do you add the license key for Froala in Angular ?(Couldn't find how to do it in froala official documentation)

Comment: Never used it, but I'm guessing it could be in the FroalaConfig that you pass at module init. 
```value('froalaConfig', {
        toolbarInline: false,
        placeholderText: 'Enter Text Here'
    });```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write `key: 'YOUR_KEY'` as a config value of your app or option value of your directive.
Source: https://github.com/froala/angular-froala/issues/132

Comment: .value('froalaConfig',{'key':'KEY'})